# Add "p = " in front of geom_boxplot p-value in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggpubr

P-values can be added to `ggplot2` figures using the function `ggpubr::stat_compare_mean()`. However I cannot get the text "p = " to show up in front of the p-values. There are examples of how to add "p = " in front of p-values on the help page for the function but they do not seem to work.

Example

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggpubr)
library(dplyr)

data("Cars93")

# List of the comparisons I would like to make for which p-values will be derived

my_comparisons <- list(c("Front", "Rear"),
                       c("Front", "4WD"),
                       c("Rear", "4WD"))

# creates the figure with p-value but no label indicating the values are p-values

Cars93 %>%
  mutate(DriveTrain = factor(DriveTrain, levels = c("Front","Rear","4WD"))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = DriveTrain, y = Price)) +
  stat_compare_means(paired = F,
                     comparisons = my_comparisons) +
  geom_boxplot(outlier.colour="white", outlier.fill = "white", outlier.shape = 1, outlier.size = 0) +
  geom_jitter(shape=1, position=position_jitter(0.2), color = "black", fill = "white", size = 2) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 16, color = "black"),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 16, color = "black"),
        axis.title = element_text(size = 16, color = "black"),
        axis.title.x = element_text(vjust = -0.5),
        panel.grid = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank())
```

following the example at the bottom of the `?stat_compare_means` page suggests using `aes(label = paste0("p = ", ..p.format..)` which does not work.

```
?stat_compare_means

Cars93 %>%
  mutate(DriveTrain = factor(DriveTrain, levels = c("Front","Rear","4WD"))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = DriveTrain, y = Price)) +
  stat_compare_means(paired = F,
                     comparisons = my_comparisons,
                     aes(label = paste0("p = ", ..p.format..))) +
  geom_boxplot(outlier.colour="white", outlier.fill = "white", outlier.shape = 1, outlier.size = 0) +
  geom_jitter(shape=1, position=position_jitter(0.2), color = "black", fill = "white", size = 2) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 16, color = "black"),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 16, color = "black"),
        axis.title = element_text(size = 16, color = "black"),
        axis.title.x = element_text(vjust = -0.5),
        panel.grid = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank())
```

If you look at the `label` argument on the `?stat_compare_means` help page it says the allowed values include `"p.signif"` or `"p.format"` which made me think `..p.format..` was deprecated, so I tried adding in `"p.format"` which also did not work.

```
Cars93 %>%
  mutate(DriveTrain = factor(DriveTrain, levels = c("Front","Rear","4WD"))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = DriveTrain, y = Price)) +
  stat_compare_means(paired = F,
                     comparisons = my_comparisons,
                     aes(label = paste0("p = ", "p.format"))) +
  geom_boxplot(outlier.colour="white", outlier.fill = "white", outlier.shape = 1, outlier.size = 0) +
  geom_jitter(shape=1, position=position_jitter(0.2), color = "black", fill = "white", size = 2) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 16, color = "black"),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 16, color = "black"),
        axis.title = element_text(size = 16, color = "black"),
        axis.title.x = element_text(vjust = -0.5),
        panel.grid = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank())
```

In the end I would like the p-values to be preceded by `p =`  such that the labels would say p = 0.00031, p = 0.059, and p = 0.027.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use a list of comparisons, `stat_compare_means` defaults to using `geom_signif` from the `ggsignif` package, essentially acting as a glorified wrapper function. In so doing, you lose some of the formatting flexibility. Better in this case to use `geom_signif` directly:

```r
library(ggsignif)

Cars93 %>%
  mutate(DriveTrain = factor(DriveTrain, levels = c("Front","Rear","4WD"))) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = DriveTrain, y = Price)) +
  geom_signif(y_position = c(55, 60, 65),
              comparisons = my_comparisons,
              map_signif_level = function(x) paste("p =", scales::pvalue(x))) +
  geom_boxplot(outlier.colour="white", outlier.fill = "white", 
               outlier.shape = 1, outlier.size = 0) +
  geom_jitter(shape=1, position=position_jitter(0.2), 
              color = "black", fill = "white", size = 2) +
  theme_bw() +
  theme(axis.text.x = element_text(size = 16, color = "black"),
        axis.text.y = element_text(size = 16, color = "black"),
        axis.title = element_text(size = 16, color = "black"),
        axis.title.x = element_text(vjust = -0.5),
        panel.grid = element_blank(),
        panel.background = element_blank())
```

[image]